# assigning values to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models, sqlite3-ruby

I'm kinda new to coding on rails. It would be great if you could help me out with what I think might be  noob question.Here's my code:

```
def create
@project = Project.new(params[:project])
if @project.save
    redirect_to new_project_path
end

student=@project.student_str.split(";")
@users = User.where(:code => student)

@users.each do |c|
puts c.email
end

@users.each do |c|
puts "I'm here"
c.projects = "#{c.projects};#{@project.id}"

end



end
```

So, in the create method, Each time a new project is created a string called student_str is stored where the ID number of each student is seperated by a ";". I split that string to an array using the split function to get an array of student ID's. I have the *puts c.email* and *puts "I'm here"* to make sure the loops are working fine. I get the proper outputs on terminal.

The problem here is the

```
c.projects = "#{c.projects};#{@project.id}"
```

That simply does not seem to be working.
My model is not updated when this line is executed. I get no errors though.
Can you tell me what I might have to do to fix this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `c.save` after you updated the projects attribute. Otherwise the object is updated but not the database so the next time you load it the changes are gone.